# grep: search inside user include files

Tags: include, grep

I want to search for string/expression in some c files using **grep** or find. Is there any ways to search in header files which is included in that c file?

eg:

### myfile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myfile1.h"
#include "myfile2.h"

void main()
{
   DATA val;  
}
```

Let I want to search for string "DATA". It should search in myfile.c and in myfile1.h,myfile2.h...

Comment: The path may contain lots of header files. I want those included in my test source file only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this might work:

```
grep -nr "DATA" path/to/files
```

- `n` is to include the line number of the file that is matched
- `r` is to search recursively on the path provided

You could also list each file specifically:

```
grep -nr "DATA" myfile.c myfile1.h myfile2.h
```

Or, if all your `.h` files are in the same directory:

```
grep -nr "DATA" *.h
```

Additionally, you can `grep` to get a list of included header files:

```
grep -o "\".*\.h\"" myfile.c
"myfile1.h"
"myfile2.h"
```

From there, you can use `xargs` to take those outputs and run the original search on each of the file names that are returned:

```
grep -o "\".*\.h\"" myfile.c | xargs grep -n "DATA"
```

include the original file in the search as well if you like:

```
grep -o "\".*\.h\"" myfile.c | xargs grep -n "DATA" myfile.c
```

Comment: The path may contain lots of header files. I want those included in my test source file only

Answer (score 0):

write a shell script, like this

1) first search the word DATA in myfile.c

```
grep -nr "DATA" myfile.c
```

2) search for the words containing the extension .h

3) now again apply the grep commands to these header files

```
grep -nr "DATA" myfile1.h myfile2.h
```